# Chain rule proof confusion

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, chain-rule

Here is a common informal proof for the chain rule:

If $S(a)=f(g(x))|_{x=a}$, then $S'(a)$ is given by

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{S(x)-S(a)}{x-a}&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{x-a} \\
&=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} \\
&=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot\lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} \\
&=f'(g(a))g'(a)
\end{align}

The reason this proof is considered informal is because it does not take into account the case where $g(x)=g(a)$ as $x \to a$. This is not, however, where my confusion lies. I am confused as to how $f'(g(a))$ equals $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$$

As far as I understand, $f'(g(a))$ means apply the function $f'$ to $g(a)$. The function $f'$, evaluated at a particular point $p$, is defined by

$$
\lim_{x \to p}\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p}
$$

Thus, $f'(g(a))$ is defined as

$$
\lim_{x \to g(a)}\frac{f(x)-f(g(a))}{x-g(a)}
$$

And so I don't see how these two expressions can be equal to each other. What am I missing?

Comment: $g$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Beware: you are using the variable $x$ in two different ways.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thank you for responding. Could you please clarify how I am using $x$ in two different ways?

Comment: Look at Pacciu's answer. They resist the temptation to use the same variable for two different things.

Comment: +1 for writing a well formed question!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. Sorry if this is inappropriate to mention here, but best of luck with your ambitions to become a moderator. I can definitely see you as someone who could defuse the conflicts which make Math.SE a less friendly community.

Comment: Thanks @joe for sharing your thoughts! However the right place for such comments is in [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32198/72031) or the [election chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110482/2020-moderator-election-chatroom).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $g$ is differentiable in $a$ and $f$ is differentiable in $g(a)$, then they are also continuous in those points; therefore $g(x) \to g(a)$ as $x\to a$ and you can use substitution $y=g(x)$ in the limit $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)}$ to get:

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)} \stackrel{y=g(x)}{=} \lim_{y\to g(a)} \frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y - g(a)} = f^\prime (g(a))\; .$$

Comment: Thank you very much. So, to clarify, we know that $g'(x)$ exists when $x=a$. Because differentiability implies continuity, we know that $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=g(a)$. This means that as $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$, $g(x)$ also gets closer and closer to $g(a)$. Therefore, $x \to a$ can be replaced with $g(x) \to g(a)$. And then, using the substitution $y=g(x)$, we can arrive at your answer.

Comment: Yep! You're right.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the reason this works is that the derivative $f'(g(a)) $ exists (it is part of hypotheses of chain rule). There may be a case when limit $\lim_{y\to g(a)} \dfrac{f(y) - f(g(a))} {y-g(a)} =f'(g(a)) $ does not exist but $\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))} {g(x) - g(a)} $ exists.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Actually, it is pointed out: “$f$ is differentiable in $g(a)$” (first line). ;-)